# Brake pad wears faster than other three

Tags: brakes, chrysler, smell, brake-calipers, brake-pad

I've changed all my calipers, all my rotors, and all my pads in an attempt to fix this problem, but it has not gone away.

My rear passenger brake pad wears fast, to the point where it begins to grind, and the left side still has a full pad. This will be my third time replacing the pad in the last 2 months. Sometimes after driving it will be really hot, and smell like burning brake - sometimes it wont. Car stops just fine, and I don't notice any pulling.

Chrysler Sebring '04 Sedan

Answer (score 3):

Since you have replaced all the calipers, the most likely issue is that the slider mechanism that the caliper rides on is seizing.

Each brake caliper holds 2 pads, if it is the slider that is at fault, then only one of the pads will be wearing down quickly.  Is that what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Mechanics SE!  It sounds to me like you have a sticky caliper that is preventing the pads in that corner of the vehicle from fully releasing when you're releasing the brake.  This could be caused by the slide pins in the caliper being corroded or needing lubricating or it could be an issue with the piston within the caliper itself.

One other thing you might want to check is to make sure that the hand brake (e-brake) cable isn't jamming or out of adjustment on that side of the car as this could prevent the brake from ever fully releasing too.

Answer (score 0):

Given you say you have already replaced the pads, rotor and caliper then it must be something else.

There are only two things that come to mind which are:
1) the pipe (metal or the rubber one) to that caliper - is it damaged and not releasing pressure?

2) the load proportioning valve has stuck and causing the brake to be held on...

The other possibility, which I consider very remote, is the abs unit.